# How to add Cookies functionality in PHP & WordPress Website for Personalisation of Website

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, web

Recently I was going through kind of search results for variety of coding websites, I saw one thing that I want to add in my website, a functionality of **Cookies**, as a developer I know that what is Cookies and how to use it but I don't know how to add this kind of functionality in my website.

[cookies functionality section which I saw on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k21F.jpg)

My Website Development is in PHP & WordPress, my main thing is how to add this kind of section on my website.

My motive behind doing this is to serve the viewer of the website according to his area of interest and visit history on my website and personalization.

Comment: aren't there plugins for that? or are you developing one..?

Comment: There must be some plugins available for that, I appreciate those but what is main that we need to setup the code by own so complete customization will be in our hands that will be even more beautiful.

Comment: if you're developing one then: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-set-get-and-delete-cookies-in-wordpress/ , otherwise just install the plugin and get the job done ..

Comment: I had just checked for available plugins in wordpress this is the exact thing which i want but i want to do it in same but in my own custom way : **https://wordpress.org/plugins/uk-cookie-consent/** now but i really need to know that what next like if we did it than suppose how can i customized my website as per my requirements based on this development.

Comment: then why'd you use wordpress in the first place? is it your own website? do you want to get it up and running fast, or you want to learn; if latter is the case, go for some framework. wordpress ain't teaching you anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to SET and then GET the cookie. And you can delete it if needed before the expire date.

To SET

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );

function setting_my_first_cookie() {
 setcookie( $v_username, $v_value, 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}

?>
```

30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS which means that the cookie will expire 30 days after creation. COOKIEPATH defines the path to your site and COOKIE_DOMAIN is the site’s domain – both these variables are set by your site.

To GET

```
<?php

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$v_username])) {
  echo "The cookie: '" . $v_username . "' is not set.";
} else {
  echo "The cookie '" . $v_username . "' is set.";
  echo "Cookie is:  " . $_COOKIE[$v_username];
}

?>
```

Comment: **Ataman** thanks for your code i already implemented this code but i need to customization of my website something like this **https://wordpress.org/plugins/uk-cookie-consent/**